# Is it true that two rigid bars welded and with corner fixed in the space must rotate with the same angular velocity?

Tags: classical-mechanics, rotational-kinematics, angular-velocity

Let's consider a point particle $A$ in motion with fixed distance from the origin. Its vector position $\mathbf{A}$ has this property:
$$
|\mathbf{A}|=\textrm{constant}
$$
By calculating $\frac{d|A|^2}{dt}=\frac{d|\mathbf{A} \cdot \mathbf{A}|}{dt}$ it is easy to see that
$$
\dot{\mathbf{A}} \cdot \mathbf{A} = 0
$$
but $\mathbf{A} \cdot \mathbf{B} = 0 \Leftrightarrow \exists !  \,\, \mathbf{C} : \mathbf{B} = \mathbf{C} \times \mathbf{A} $ (choosing the right $\mathbf{\hat{C}}$, I can get, in the infinite direction orthogonal to $\mathbf{A}$, the right one to match $\mathbf{B}$, and choosing the right $C=|\mathbf{C}|$ I can get the right magnitude too) so (LaTeX bm command doesn't work here so I can't bold greek letters)
$$
\exists !  \,\, \mathbf{\omega} : \dot{\mathbf{A}} = \mathbf{\omega} \times \mathbf{A}
$$
that is, in each instant $t$, $\mathbf{A}$ is rotating about an axis (that can moving in time of course). Now I consider two vectors with fixed magnitude and fixed angle between them
$$
|\mathbf{A}|=C_1
$$
$$
|\mathbf{B}|=C_2
$$
$$
\mathbf{A}\cdot\mathbf{B}=C_3
$$
the first two says (in the light of what we saw before)
$$
\dot{\mathbf{A}} = \mathbf{\omega}_A \times \mathbf{A}
$$
$$
\dot{\mathbf{B}} = \mathbf{\omega}_B \times \mathbf{B}
$$
while the last one says
$$
\dot{\mathbf{A}} \cdot \mathbf{B} + 
\dot{\mathbf{B}} \cdot \mathbf{A} = 0
$$
It would be very interesting to show that we must have $ \mathbf{\omega}_A = \mathbf{\omega}_B $ but I failed in this goal. Substituting $\dot{\mathbf{A}}$ and $\dot{\mathbf{B}}$ in the last equation it is easy to rearrange into
$$
(\mathbf{A} \times \mathbf{B}) \cdot ( \mathbf{\omega}_A - \mathbf{\omega}_B ) = 0
$$
but this doesn't look so useful as it look at first glance. If only I were able to proof that
$$
\mathbf{\omega}_A \neq \mathbf{\omega}_B \quad \Rightarrow \quad ( \mathbf{A} \times \mathbf{B} ) \not\perp ( \mathbf{\omega}_A - \mathbf{\omega}_B ) 
$$
then the proof would be ended, but I don't know if this is the right way to go on in the proof. I tried to do it by exploiting vector identities but it seems that this doesn't work...

Comment: The three equations you used do not necessarily define a rigid motion. Imagine point B rotating about A, and A rotating about another arbitrary axis. you will still have A=c1 B=c2 and A.B=c3

Comment: I am not sure if considering   |AxB|=c4 will help

Comment: $\vec{\omega}_A=\vec{\omega}_B$ only if $\vec{A}=\vec{B}$

Comment: @Wolphram_jonny I don't see why a rigid "V" couldn't nove in the way you say. A segment rotating around the other, while this other rotating around an axes. This don't seem compromise rigidity. I wrong?

Comment: @Eli your comment is obscure to me, why two different vectors (say i and j of a standard basis rotating) cannot move with the same $\vec{\omega}$?

Comment: @FaustoVezzaro in your case is $\vec{\omega}_A=\frac{\vec{A}\times \vec{\dot{A}}}{|A|^2}$ and  $\vec{\omega}_B=\frac{\vec{B}\times \vec{\dot{B}}}{|B|^2}$  so if $\vec{\omega}_A=\vec{\omega}_B$  thus  $\vec{A}$ must equal $\vec{B}$ ?

Comment: @Eli $\vec{A} \times \vec{\dot{A}} = |A|^2 \vec{\omega}_A - (\vec{\omega}_A \cdot \vec{A}) \vec{A}$ but in general $\vec{\omega}_A \not\perp \vec{A}$.

Comment: I think you are right, and I was wrong, but now I am confused: if A  moves on the xy plane then $\omega_A$ points in the z direction, but I fail to see how  $\omega_B$ points also in the z direction, even if it is rigid.

Comment: I think are right. I guess I can't prove what I'm trying to prove for the simple reason that the thesis is false. $|\vec {\omega}_B|$ is not the angular velocity with which B rotates around A, but they can be different (among other things, for example, $\vec {\omega}_B$ varies in time while $\vec {\omega}_A$ not). I was trying to put a patch on something that doesn't come back to me in the introduction and the study of the relative motions in case of rotation. But I have to think about it.

Comment: If both A and B of the rigid V move with *constant* angular velocity, then $\vec{\omega}_B =\vec{\omega}_A$, this sounds much more reasonable.